# How to Auto-run a batch file

Tags: autorun

How do i auto-run a .bat (batch) file?
Meaning, I have a .bat file which registers me for few things and there are a few errors in the batch file which is fine. I just go on clicking 'ok' a few times to ignore these error messages, which seems monotonous. Kindly help me to solve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can call it from your `autoexec.bat` file and it will run automatically.  For example, if your file is `commands.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
PROMPT $P$G
PATH C:\DOS;C:\WINDOWS
SET TEMP=C:\TEMP
SET BLASTER=A220 I7 D1 T2
LH SMARTDRV.EXE
LH DOSKEY
LH MOUSE.COM /Y
C:\COMMANDS.BAT
WIN
```